# How to quickly execute a python file on Mac

Tags: python, macos, command

I'm a beginner of Python and today I learned a new program that can search a place with Google Maps. This is the code:

```
import webbrowser, sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    address = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
else:
    address = pyperclip.paste()

webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + address)
```

My file name is `mapit.py` and I really want to know that I can execute by only typing, for example,

```
mapit New York
```

in the root command line instead of

```
Pycharm\......\pythoh3 mapit.py New York
```

I've tried to execute `mapit.py New York` on Spotlight search, but it didn't work.

Comment: You need to add python before that given that the python installation directory is included in path environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to achieve is to register a custom command with your script, right? To do this, you use aliases:

```
$ alias mapit="python3 ...\mapit.py"
```

put the real path to the mapit.py instead of '...\mapit.py'

Then you can use the alias as a command:

```
$ mapit "New York"
```

Comment: Thank you, however, after finishing this, I ran mapit "New York", it showed zsh: permission denied: /Users/edward/PycharmProjects/Pratical_function/mapit.py.

Comment: You need to change the permissions on the file then. Use chmod command to do it. $ chmod 754 /Users/edward/PycharmProjects/Pratical_function/mapit.py

Answer (score 0):

To simply run a Python script, you can either invoke Python and pass the script

```
python mapit.py someargument "some argument with spaces"
```

Or you can add the proper Python shebang to the top of the script and enable the [executable bit](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/415)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import webbrowser, sys, pyperclip
some_code_here ...
```

If you then want to make this even simpler, you can [set up an alias](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25250?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) for `show_me` or something else to `python /path/to/mapit.py`. Then you can simple call `show_me "New York"`.

As a side note, if you call `python /path/to/mapit.py New York`, it will parse `New` and `York` to be two separate arguments. If you want them to be one single argument, you will need to wrap them in quotes as such:

```
python /path/to/mapit.py "New York"
```